# why sizeof(function_name) is 1

Tags: c, sizeof

Why is the result of:

```
sizeof(function_name)?
```

`1`? Somebody in community said that `sizeof(main)` is 1 but `sizeof(main())` is 4. Here `main` is returning `int`, so it is returning 4. but if we do declaration as `char main()` instead of `int main()` it will return 1 only.

Comment: Should that even compile?

Comment: @MartinJames hmmm, `gcc` allows `main` to return char but gives a warning `clang` gives an error. I think I would prefer it to be an error.

Answer (score 3):

It's illegal to use `sizeof` on a function.

> #### C99 §6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` operator
>
> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
>   incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that
>   designates a bit-field member.

So if `foo` is the function name, `sizeof(foo)` is illegal, but `sizeof(foo())` applies `sizeof` on the return value of `foo()`. `main()` returns `int` in standard C, it's 4 bytes on most machines today.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(char)` equals `1`, always and everywhere.

So everything declared `char` would do also, and this already at compile-time.